# Want to call Main Activity when button in Expandablelistview is clicked android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an `Expandablelistview` with a button which deletes items from the database which feeds the `listview`. The items are getting deleted, but I need to leave the activity and go back to it to see the item gone. I thought of just calling the main activity, but the `startActivity(intent)` is underlined in red. I have tried all sorts. Please can someone help. Thank you

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
{
    final String item = (String)this.getGroup(i);

    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, null);
    }

    final TextView itemTV = view.findViewById(R.id.parent_shopping_item);
    itemTV.setText(item);
    CheckBox checkBox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
    Button deleteItemBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked)
        {
            itemTV.setPaintFlags(itemTV.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
            if (! isChecked)
            {
                itemTV.setPaintFlags(itemTV.getPaintFlags() & (~Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
            }
        }
    });

    deleteItemBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(context, null, null, 1);
            dbManager.deleteItem(item);
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think calling

```
 yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of trying to call your activity again, will update your listView.

Comment: Do you update your list after deleting an item from database?

Comment: That is what I am trying to achieve, but not having much luck. If i leave the activity with the list on it and then return the deleted item is gone. I would like it to be instant.

Comment: You can fetch the items from database into your list, after you made an update to the database and call the notify method. What i mean is you need to recreate your list and notify the adapter after a change. If you don't want to recreate your list each time there is a change, you can delete an item from both the database and the list and notify the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to add in the **onClick** method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view)
{
    DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(context, null, null, 1);
    dbManager.deleteItem(item);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    startActivity(context, intent, bundle);
}
```